# Looping through all sub directories in a folder?

Tags: shell-script, shell, for

I have requirement where in I need print relative path of each folder.

Folder structure is

[image]

is there any way by using single **for** loop I can print absolute path.

output :-

```
image_script
image_script/artifactory
image_script/artifactory/charts
image_script/artifactory/charts/postgressql
image_script/artifactory/charts/postgressql/templates
image_script/artifactory/templates
```

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Your sample output shows relative paths, not absolute ones. Also, do you just want to list them in your terminal or will the paths be the input for something else?

Comment: sorry it is relative paths , yes I need to execute few commands in each folder

Comment: Please amend your question to describe the full problem then. Printing some names may be different from doing something with them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
find `pwd` -type d
```

Or replace pwd by the absolute path of your folder

Comment: With bash, you can use `"$PWD"` instead of calling `pwd`. Also, it's preferable to use `$(...)` instead of backticks

Answer (score 2):

To get the pathnames of all directories from the top-most `image_script` directory:

```
find image_script -type d
```

This will include the `image_script` directory itself.

To get *absolute* pathnames, i.e. pathnames that start with a `/`, specify the full path to the `image_script` directory on the `find` command line.

Use `find images_script -depth -type d` to get the pathnames in a depth-first ordering.

With `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar
printf '%s\n' image_script/**/
```

The `globstar` shell option enables the use of `**` to match across `/` in pathnames.  This would output all directory pathnames with a trailing `/` though.  To avoid that:

```
shopt -s globstar
for pathname in image_script/**/; do
    printf '%s\n' "${pathname%/}"
done
```

Comment: `**` matching is turned on with `globstar` instead of `extglob`, right?

Comment: @Haxiel That's absolutely true! Thanks! I don't know what I was thinking...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) for it.

```
$ tree -d -f -i /path/to/root_folder
```

`-d` prints only directory.

`-f` prepend the full path.

`-i` is used for not printing indentation lines.

fin swimmer

Comment: It would add some extra lines to the end of the output though. Use it with `-s` too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for` loop might not be the best option here, better use `find`:

```
cd /PATH/TO/image_script/..
find image_script -type d
```

If you need the absolute path you can use

```
find /PATH/TO/image_script -type d
```